# How can I view the contents of "/var/www" in browser, like 'wamp' in windows OS?

Tags: php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm new for PHP.  I've installed Apache, MySQL, PHPmyadmin in Ubuntu 10.10.

Is there any way to access the contents(folder/files) of `/var/www` in browser like 'wamp' in windows OS?

Comment: If your apache server is running then you should be able to access the files under /var/www in browser by using http://localhost. Hope you know this.

Answer (score 2):

You can usually do this calling it via "localhost" (http://localhost) in a web browser.

In a File Browser you can gain access to these files by opening the folders with a file browser with elevated privileges. (for read/write access) Try **Alt+F2** and `gksudo nautilus`, then hit **Ctrl+L** and write `/var/www` and hit **Enter** in order to be directed to the folder.

***After reading your comment I edited this answer.***

I can't say a suggestion for such a tool like a full featured GUI for all these requirements but you can install services like:

## **[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)**

[image]

## [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/)

(third party) 
[image]

And a few other in order to manage these tasks.

For the case of Apache version you simply run a `phpinfo.php` file with the next code inside:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

This file is suggested to be at the very root of the `/var/www` and can be invoked by dropping `http://locahost/phpinfo.php` in your web browser.

The `/var/www` is simply the canvas. You can fill it with whatever tools you wish, including your website itself but for productivity  you may wish to include a few additional non-public services like those I have mentioned over here.

Good luck!

Comment: I meant the same way wamp gui...
while clicking localhost in wamp, the (http://localhost) displays WAMP icon, version
apache version
php version
mysql version
 and some links like:
Tools
Your projects
Your aliases

while clicking "Your projects" link it displays the contents(folder/files) of "WAMP5/www" folder as links with icons.

but, in linux...
(http://localhost) displays 
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: Ok, I have edited this answer in the hope that this information is useful for you. If not, please let us know. Thank you